# ruby private methods calling public methods of a different class

Tags: ruby, oop

Is it considered a good design to allow a private method in `class A` in ruby to call a public method in `class B`,

I guess a better approach would be to call another public method in `class A` which would call the public method in `class B`.

Consider a situation where a user needs to act (private method) on a resource but can't do so without examining some constraint (through a public method) of the resource.

Comment: what is the hierarchical relationship....?

Comment: tbh there are no relationships at the moment, it could be anything like a `user` class and a `house` class, if the user wants to enter the house he needs to check if the house is safe...I'm just thinking out loud to give an example.

Comment: @Subash can you give a practical example, i.e. two Ruby classes (`House` and `User`) containing meaningful public and private methods?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exact function you want, but it's no problem to allow a private method in class A in ruby to call a public method in class B like the code :

```
class A

  private

  def test_a
    B.new.test_b
  end

end


class B

  def test_b
    puts 'test_b'
  end

end


A.new.send(:test_a) #=>test_b
```

Comment: Hi @Tsao I know it can be done that way, I'm concerned over the good design and best practises issue here, Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Two other situations that are common are 1) the private method calling a (public) Class or Module method (e.g, `x = Math.sqrt(y)`) and 2) a public instance method returning an instance of another class and passing that instance to the private method.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it considered a good design to allow a private method in class A in
>   ruby to call a public method in class B

It doesn't matter whether you're calling the external class from a public or private method, as private methods are an implementation detail. What matters is whether it makes sense for the given class to know about that external classes' method.

> Consider a situation where a user needs to act (private method) on a resource but can't do so without examining some constraint (through a public method) of the resource.

Taking into account your comment:

> if the user wants to enter the house he needs to check if the house is safe

One possible implementation would be:

```
class User
  def enter(house)
    if house.safe?
      house.users << user
    end
  end
end
```

This requires the `User` class to know a few things about the `House` class:

- it implements a safety validation via `#safe?`
- it stores entered users in a `users` array

This means `User` knows quite a bit about `House`. If `House` changes the implementation of the above two items, `User` needs to change too.

An alternate design would be to invert the owner of the functionality:

```
def House
  def entry_for(user)
    if safe?
      users << user
    end
  end
end
```

Now, the coupling between these two classes has been reduced. As the owner of the `safe?` constraint, `House` controls whether users are allowed in while `User` remains blissfully ignorant of the implementation of `House`.

Depending on the domain in question, the assertion of safety might belong to a class other than `House` or `User`, eg. `Guard`. In this case, you might end up with something like:

```
class Guard
  def facilitate_entry(user, house)
    house.enter_by(user) if safe?(house)
  end

  private

  def safe?(house)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to say, and thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that would be a good approach, to create a public methods to access other class's public methods. You would get overwhelmed with too many public methods in your class.

As Ruby is pure object oriented and everything is object there. If you go with that approach in mind, you will ended up with unnecessary methods. Even if you are doing simple stuff in your private method. Let say you are trying to  iterating an array with `each` method. Would you consider creating a public methods to first to access public method `each` of class Array ? Answer is simply no.

Also ruby is an expressive and productive language. You could do more is less code in ruby.